# how to split string and assign it to arey with adding some parts in python

Tags: python

I have some string which contains parts separated by commas and need to add some part to each and assign all to array of variables.

the string looks like

```
chp_algos = 'AES256_SSE','AES128_CBC','AES64_CBC','AES33_CBC'
```

I want to put in array which looks like:

```
arr = [
  [AES128_CBC],
  [AES128_CBC_fer],
  [AES128_SSE],
  [AES128_SSE_fer],
  [AES64_CBC],
  [AES64_CBC_fer],
  [AES33_CBC],
  [AES33_CBC_fer]
]
```

and I want to map the following final result to db

```
f = 'AES128_CBC_fer AES128_SSE_fer AES64_CBC_fer AES33_CBC_fer'
```

Comment: The question is not clear. Could you please add more details? Do you see `chp_algos` as a string or a tuple? What does it mean _"to put in array"_?

Comment: From what I understand `arr` is just an intermediate means to your end result of `f`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the question, `chp_algos` is a tuple, not a string. So, it is already "split"

I'd recommend not using a list of lists. Just create a list of strings.

```
from itertools import chain
arr = list(chain.from_iterable([x, x + '_fer'] for x in chp_algos))
```

Output

```
['AES256_SSE',
 'AES256_SSE_fer',
 'AES128_CBC',
 'AES128_CBC_fer',
 'AES64_CBC',
 'AES64_CBC_fer',
 'AES33_CBC',
 'AES33_CBC_fer']
```

With that, you can filter.

But you could also just skip `arr` and build a new list from concatenating to the original string values

```
f = ' '.join(x for x in arr if x.endswith('_fer'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by sorting `chp_algos` then using f strings in a generator expression

```
>>> ' '.join(f'{i}_fer' for i in sorted(chp_algos))
'AES128_CBC_fer AES256_SSE_fer AES33_CBC_fer AES64_CBC_fer'
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify your string `chp_algos`? The way you wrote it now it is not compatible with python.

Anyway, what you can do in your case, assuming that `chp_algos` is a string of the form `chp_algos= "'AES256_SSE','AES128_CBC','AES64_CBC','AES33_CBC'"`, then you can split the string into a list of strings via `chp_algos.split(",")`.

The argument of `split()` is the delimiter which should be used to split the string.

Now you have something like `array = ["'AES256_SSE'", "'AES128_CBC'", "'AES64_CBC'", "'AES33_CBC'"]`.

To get the array that you want you can just do a simple loop through your array:

```
arr = []
for element in array:
    arr.append([element])
    arr.append([element + str("_fer")])
```

Now you might have some issues with the quotes (depends on how your data looks like). But these you can just remove by looking at the relevant indices of element. To do this just replace `element` in the code above by `element[1:-2]`. This removes the first and the last element of the string.

To get the f string in the very end, you can just loop through arr[1::2] which returns every 2nd element of arr starting at the second one (index 1).

Comment: It is compatible. Try it. It makes a tuple

Comment: Ah, interesting. Thx

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a string:

```
s = 'AES256_SSE,AES128_CBC,AES64_CBC,AES33_CBC'
```

In order to replace commas with a space and append a suffix to each part:

```
' '.join(f'{p}_fer' for p in s.split(','))
```

As for an array:

```
def g(s):
    for s in s.split(','):
        yield s
        yield f'{s}_fer'

arr = [*g(s)]
```